# Asp.net MVC Wysiwyg EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented CKEditor via an EditorTemplate called wysiwyg.ascx

Everything loads fine in edit view, when I attempt to save the model back to the database via POST Edit ActionResult in the controller.  the property that uses the wysiwyg comes back null.  I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Can you post the part of the view in which the CKEditor is defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.TextArea**("Description",** Model, 5, 100, new { @class = "ckeditor" })%>
```

The problem was due to the Name.  "Description" clear Description and replace with "".